# Latent heat and change of state

Tags: thermodynamics, water, gas

If 1kg of water at 100℃ is supplied with less amount of heat energy than the latent heat of vaporisation,what will happen to it?Does part of it undergo phase change while the rest remain same?Or the entire heat is absorbed yet the temperature remains 100℃?

Comment: Both; if the heating transfers less energy than the corresponding latent heat for the entire 1 kg, the final state is some liquid and some gas, both at 100°C.

Comment: Is the amount of liquid that turns to gas is= (Heat energy supplied/Latent heat)?;where heat supplied<latent heat

Comment: That’s correct. Make sure your units all match up.

Comment: You cannot supply "less amount of heat energy than the heat of vaporization". The "heat" and "heat of vaporization" are different types of quantities with different units. Comparing them does not make sense. It's like comparing distance in meters with velocity in m/s. You cannot travel a distance less than the speed of sound in air, for example.

Comment: @nasu I believe the intended meaning is "heated with less energy than required to vaporize the entire sample." "Heat of vaporization" here refers to the total enthalpy of vaporization, measured in joules (in SI). Sometimes we normalize this to mass or molar amount for convenience, but as you note, unit mismatch precludes this interpretation here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any amount of heat transfer to the water will start converting the liquid to a vapor. The amount that is vapor and the amount that is liquid coexisting together at 100 C as a result of the heat transfer will depend on the amount of heat transferred to the water. Given the latent heat of vaporization at 1 atm of about 2.25 kJ/kg, all the water will be a vapor after 2.25 kJ of heat is transferred. Before that, the heat will be absorbed with no temperature change.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't enough heat added to the water, it won't vaporize completely. At 100°C (assuming 1 atm, closed system), water will exist as a gas-liquid mixture. When you add heat to the system, this will shift the ratio of gas-to-liquid higher so some of it will change phase. The amount of liquid that turns into gas is dependent on the amount of heat added and in turn the temperature (for a constant pressure system). This is also dependent on the equation of state among other things.